# Audio noiseless video becomes noisy after importing in windows movie maker

Tags: video, video-editor, audio-quality, noise, noise-reduction

I am getting a problem whenever I import a video having formats in `wmv & avi` in `windows movie maker`, the audio becomes **noisy** I dont why it is happening may be is it the bitrate issue or something else please advice me on this as I have to stick with `Windows movie maker`.

I am using **Adobe Soundbooth** to reduce noise but after `exporitng` from `Adobe soubdbooth` video's audio becomes noisy only in `windows movie maker` else it is fine.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in particular that should cause this other than the fact that Windows movie maker is horrible.  It is likely an issue with the bitrate of audio that Movie Maker exports and I'm not sure if there is anything that can be done about this.  If you can buy even a fairly basic and well reviewed consumer targeted editing software you would probably be far better off.

Answer (score 1):

Try seperating the audio and video streams of the WMV and AVI files - I don't have an app in mind but there should be some free ones avaliable. Put the video part in, which will remain in the original format (WMV or AVI) and should work. For the audio, use Soundbooth to convert it into a variety of formats like WAV, MP3, WMV, etc. until the import works without noise. I don't use MM now, but I have before and know for a fact that there are no problems with importing MP3 files.